# CPU in node.js Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js

i'm using node.js in my Windows 7 and have a stack of a banch async function and run it as

```
stack = {
nextStep: function() {
  if (this.run) return;
  this.run = true;

  /* Do some stuff, example for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) console.log(i); */

  this.run = false;
}
};

setInterval(stack.nextStep.bind(stack), 5);
```

I have a ton of task, which must be performed.

They run very slowly, but CPU usage is over 2-3% !!!! I don't know why it's so lower value, i think, it's must be over 90% CPU usage. What i'm doing wrong?

I already try reduce setInterval timer to 0, but it is not work. CPU usage in windows task manager all times over 2-3% (except some times, when nodejs V8 get 8-9%, but it is immediately passes).

So, question is - how can i force node.js to use a maximum of CPU to perform a task faster? Or where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically node.js is single threaded model per process.
Even if u have multi core machine, Node.JS cannot use all CPU at the time.
to use whole cpu, u need to use node cluster. it invokes multiple process and the process will use other CPU.

Because of this reason, vert.x (simillar to node.js) is more faster than node.js